# Recovering Twitter Account Created on Android Device?

Tags: twitter

A friend of mine has created a Twitter account on their phone but now can not remember any of the details they used. They remain logged in on their phone but I've had a look through the app but it doesn't seem to mention anything useful.

Have I missed something? I have a adb backup (and the password) to look through if that helps.

Comment: Are we talking official twitter app on android?

Comment: The twitter account should be connected to an e-mail adress. If it is, you always have the "I forgot my password" route available to you. Also, if you have the password, what is the problem? The username is in plain sight (twitter.com/user) and that's all you need except for the password.

Comment: Yes, the official app. Unfortunately the email address is unknown as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up contacting Twitter support and they verified ownership of the account using a DM.

Answer (score 1):

Take a backup of the same Twitter client on your phone, with a known handle and email, and then search the resulting files (or backup image) for the know handle and email.  Then look in the same place on the original image/files.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the Twitter app saves the password, it most likely saves some kind of tokens that gives it access to the account as long as the token doesn't expire.